# What files specfically contain the Kaa-node IP address

Tags: iot, platform, kaa

I have a quick question.

I've spent a couple of hours Googling this but I can't seem to find an answer.

Where exactly in the Kaa C SDK is the host IP address of the kaa-node embedded? I know that each time you update the IP address of the Sandbox using the Management page, you have to regenerate the SDK. But in my case, the SDK that has generated has taken me many hours to debug and fix, and I would not like to repeat that process all over again.

Instead, I would prefer just fixing the one or two files that contain the updated IP address. But does anyone know which files these are?

I've heard that they are in the bootstrap extension header files. Is this true?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the SDK generation (for security purposes), a list of the available bootstrap nodes are embedded on a header file (except Java SDK). This header file is saved as **kaa_defaults.h** and can be encountered in your generated C SDK files.

If you wanna see the C SDK generation code, you can find it [here](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/release-0.10/server/node/src/main/java/org/kaaproject/kaa/server/control/service/sdk/CSdkGenerator.java).

I don't think you'll be able to change manually the address on this file, or if there's another way instead of re-generating a SDK with the new address of your instances.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed. I believe if I regenerate the SDK with the proper IP in my management page, the defaults file will be correct.

In theory, could I swap out the defaults file from the newly generated SDK and and the defaults file from my old one? Or would that cause issues.

Comment: You wanna swap the files to check if the SDK will connect to the old address given on the old generated file?

Comment: Essentially, yes.